# how do I hide file extension in PHP?

Tags: .htaccess

I tried many commands like the following

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]
```

in .htaccess to hide the php extension from the URL but do not work, I have the following site.org/home.php and I want it to site.org/home, how can I do this? Is it possible to do it without modifying .htaccess file as well?

I tried this as well in the .htaccess file and doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: No the code explained do not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually "hide" the extension using `.htaccess` (if that is what you are expecting). You must first remove the `.php` extension in your HTML source, in your internal links (Apache/`.htaccess` should not be used to do this). The extension is now "hidden" (but the links don't work).

You then use `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the extensionless URL back to the `.php` extension in order to make the URL "work".

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite to append ".php" extension if the file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

Given a request for `/home`, the above will internally rewrite the request to `/home.php` if `home.php` exists as a physical file in the document root.

Note that this rule does assume your URLs do not end in a slash. eg. It expects `/home` and not `/home/`. if you request `/home/` then it will result in a 404, since `/home/.php` does not exist.

The preceding condition first checks that the requested URL + `.php` exists as a physical file before rewriting the request. This is necessary in order to prevent a rewrite loop (500 error).

If your URLs do not contain dots (that are otherwise used to delimit the file extension) then the above can be optimised by excluding dots in the matched URL-path. ie. Change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `(.+)` to `^([^.]+)$`. This avoids your static resources (`.css`, `.js`, `.jpg`, etc.) being unnecessarily checked for the corresponding `.php` file.

If you are changing an existing URL structure that previously used the `.php` extension and these URLs have been indexed by search engines and/or linked to by third parties then you should also redirect requests that include `.php` in order to preserve SEO. This redirect should go *before* the above rewrite, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Redirect to remove ".php" extension
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The preceding *condition* that checks against the `REDIRCT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests are stripped of the `.php` extension and not rewritten requests by the later rewrite (which would otherwise result in a redirect loop).

NB: Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid potential caching issues.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]
> ```

This does considerably more than simply "removing" (or rather "appending") the `.php` extension.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine  on
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
> </IfModule>
> ```

This will result in a rewrite-loop, ie. a 500 Internal Server Error response as it will repeatedly append the `.php` extension again and again to the same request.

(The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.)

Comment: how do I remove the .php extension in my source code? do I save index.php as an index text file?

Comment: @Ahmet the same way you created the links in the first place, but remove the `.php` part. (?!)